# Implementing Factory Pattern and Gettingt NullPointerException, unable to figure out can somebody help me to fix

Tags: nullpointerexception, factory-pattern

I am posting this code in which I implemented factory method,Code is compiled successfully but null pointer exception occurs at run time and I am unable to figure it out, I know when an object reference points to nothing then this Exception occurs but in my case I am unable to figure out,Can somebody suggest me the fix here I am posting the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
abstract class Plan
{
 protected double rate;

public abstract void getRate();

public void calculateBill(int totalUnitsConsume)
{
    System.out.println(totalUnitsConsume*rate);
}

}   


  class DomesticPlan extends Plan
  {
   public void getRate()
   {
    rate=3.5;
    }
  }

 class CommercialPlan extends Plan
 {
public void getRate()
 {
 rate=7.50;
 }

 }

class InstitutionalPlan extends Plan
 {
 public void getRate()
 {
  rate=5.50;
  }

  }

 class PlanFactory
 {
  public static Plan getPlan(String planType)
  {
  if(planType==null)
 {
  return null;
  }

   if (planType.equalsIgnoreCase("DOMESTIC PLAN"))
  {
   return new DomesticPlan();
  }
   else if(planType.equalsIgnoreCase("COMMERCIAL PLAN"))   
    { 
     return new CommercialPlan();
      }
       else if (planType.equalsIgnoreCase("INSTITUTION PLAN"))
        {
        return new InstitutionalPlan();
          }



     return null;

    }
    }


    public class ElectricityBill
    {
       public static void main(String ... qwe)
     {

     int choice;
    System.out.println("Choose The Plan type");
    System.out.println("1.Domestic Plan");
    System.out.println("2.Commercial Plan");
    System.out.println("3.Institution Plan");

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    choice=sc.nextInt();
    if(choice>3)
    {
      System.out.println("Wrong choice entered");
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("You chose Plan no.:"+ choice);
    }
     switch(choice)
    {
    case 1 : Plan p=PlanFactory.getPlan("DomesticPlan");
             p.getRate();
             p.calculateBill(100);  
             break;

   case 2 : Plan p2=PlanFactory.getPlan("CommercialPlan");
            p2.getRate(); 
            p2.calculateBill(300);
            break;

   case 3 : Plan p3=PlanFactory.getPlan("InstitutionalPlan");
            p3.getRate();  
            p3.calculateBill(250); 
            break;
  default : System.out.println("May be you entered wrong choice");
       }



       }
       }
 Output

 I:\Data>java ElectricityBill
 Choose The Plan type
 1.Domestic Plan
 2.Commercial Plan
 3.Institution Plan
 1
 You chose Plan no.:1
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ElectricityBill.main(ElectricityBill.java:96)
```

Comment: Put a `System.out.println()` where you `return null;`, so you can see it happening.

Comment: you are right Erik,My If block is not executing
        if(planType==null)
         {          System.out.println("If Block");
           return null;
             }

Comment: Can you suggest the fix for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
51. planType.equalsIgnoreCase("DOMESTIC PLAN")
...
96. PlanFactory.getPlan("DomesticPlan")
```

Here none of the `if...else` block is getting executed, thus `getPlan` is returning `null`.

Please change `"DomesticPlan"` to `"DOMESTIC PLAN"` in line 96

Answer (score 0):

You missed a space inside 'DomesticPlan`in your code, so your factory can not match any string and returns null, just correct it to`Domestic Plan`

Comment: Hii hank you all of you for suggesting me the best solution I implemented your solutions one by one  but still my code throws NullPointer Exception, is there any other problem in the code

Comment: Thank you all of you.. My problem is fixed I Made suggested changes and the "save as" again and this is how changes made work

Answer (score 0):

It's because your factory is not returning a plan in that case.  You are doing `PlanFactory.getPlan("DomesticPlan")` (no space in DomesticPlan) but within your getPlan method you are looking for "DOMESTIC PLAN" (with space) and therefore `Plan p` is null.  The exception is thrown immediately after, where you are calling the `getRate` method on the null Plan.

You should null-check when you get a value from the factory, e.g. `if (p != null) { p.getRate(); ... }`